# Leaflet - How to disable click event on your overlay shapes

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I created a [leaflet map](http://unesperimentoveloce.altervista.org/map/experiment.html), with national and regional boundaries (geojson). I have a problem: I would like the national borders that are in the foreground but at the same time i don't want miss the leaflet interaction with the regional level. How can I do?

I hope my question is clear, if not I try to improve!
thank to all

<<-- EDITED -->
i found this style propriety:

```
clickable
Boolean true    If false, 
the vector will not emit mouse events and will act as a part of the underlying map.
```

it's [works](http://unesperimentoveloce.altervista.org/map/experiment2.html) :)! but i have some problem with interaction that erase national border

<<--EDIT

I fix the problem with an inefficient patch

```
function resetHighlight(e) {
        geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
        map.removeLayer(nuts0)
        map.addLayer(nuts0)
        info.update();
    };
```

Comment: Maybe when you highlight it, you can set the shape `fillOpacity` to be `0`.

Comment: i found this style propriety:  
clickable
Boolean true If false, 
the vector will not emit mouse events and will act as a part of the underlying map.

it's work!:)

Comment: Then the question should be How to disable click event on your overlay shapes. I thought that, you want to interact with your feature objects, while displaying your base map..